# Emails address on two cell phones

Tags: google

How do I delete 1 googled  account on two phones?
One google email on two phones with different phone numbers how doI delete without losing apps.

Answer (score 2):

One can remove Google Account from a device without any loss of apps installed.

However it is necessary to add atleast one Google Account in a device to enable downloading apps from playstore or using any Google App within the device.

To remove - Open Settings/Accounts/Google

Tap on Google account you want to remove and tap 3 dots on the upper right corner of the screen. Choose 'Remove Account'.

And remember to add an Google Account if you don't have any logged in after removing existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings -> Accounts -> service provider(google or whatever it is) -> click on account -> click on the 3 dots at top -> remove this account

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Personal > Accounts > Google > select account that you want to delete > menu(top right) > Remove account